# Sql result set transformer is returning array of strings

Tags: spring, hibernate

How to return a json object instead of a json string array using `SqlResultSetMappings` or `ResultTransformer`. Here is the output i got when using `SqlResultSetMappings` or `ResultTransformer`

```
[
    "Mel Bale ",
    "B.A.",
    "Interior Designer",
    "Daosa",
    "n/a"
]
```

what i want is like this

```
{
   "name":"Mel Bale ",
   "qualification":"B.A.",
   "Job":"Interior Designer",
   "location":"Daosa",
   "phone":"n/a"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define @SqlResultSetMappings like this so that your data are mapped as JSON

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "findAllDataMapping",
    classes = @ConstructorResult(
            targetClass = Sample.class,
            columns = {
                    @ColumnResult(name = "name"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "qualification"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "Job"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "location"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "phone")
            }
    )
)
```